# loading two textures on a GLSurfaceView one as background, one as foreground with alpha

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, alpha

I've set up a `GLSurfaceView` and want to do this :

- load a texture as a background(make it fullscreen without stretching the image)
- load another texture with alpha, make it foreground. so the background picture is visible, like applying a fog effect or rain effect. (also fullscreen without stretching the image)
- and any info on how to load a texture properly and set it on `GLSurfaceView` is appreciated.

and I have tried this code to load a texture on my `GLSurfaceView` but didn't work for me :

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

public class TextureHelper {
/**
 * Helper method to load a GL texture from a bitmap
 *
 * Note that the caller should "recycle" the bitmap
 *
 * @return the ID of the texture returned from glGenTextures()
 */
public static int loadGLTextureFromBitmap( Bitmap bitmap, GL10 gl ) {

    // Generate one texture pointer
    int[] textureIds = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures( 1, textureIds, 0 );

    // bind this texture
    gl.glBindTexture( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIds[0] );

    // Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR );
    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR );

    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT );
    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT );

    // Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0 );

    return textureIds[0];
}

/**
 * Create a texture from a given resource
 * 
 * @param resourceID the ID of the resource to be loaded
 * @param scaleToPO2 determines whether the image should be scaled up to the next highest power
 * of two, or whether it should be "inset" into such an image. Having textures that are
 * dimensions of some power-of-two is critical for performance in opengl.
 *
 * @return the ID of the texture returned from glGenTextures()
 */
public static int loadGLTextureFromResource( int resourceID, Context context, boolean scaleToPO2 , GL10 gl ) {

    // pull in the resource
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Drawable image = resources.getDrawable( resourceID );
    float density = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;

    int originalWidth = (int)(image.getIntrinsicWidth() / density);
    int originalHeight = (int)(image.getIntrinsicHeight() / density);

    int powWidth = getNextHighestPO2( originalWidth );
    int powHeight = getNextHighestPO2( originalHeight );

    if ( scaleToPO2 ) {
        image.setBounds( 0, 0, powWidth, powHeight );
    } else {
        image.setBounds( 0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight );
    }

    // Create an empty, mutable bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( powWidth, powHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 );
    // get a canvas to paint over the bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bitmap );
    bitmap.eraseColor(0);

    image.draw( canvas ); // draw the image onto our bitmap

    int textureId = loadGLTextureFromBitmap( bitmap , gl );

    bitmap.recycle();

    return textureId;
}

/**
 * Calculates the next highest power of two for a given integer.
 *
 * @param n the number
 * @return a power of two equal to or higher than n
 */
public static int getNextHighestPO2( int n ) {
    n -= 1;
    n = n | (n >> 1);
    n = n | (n >> 2);
    n = n | (n >> 4);
    n = n | (n >> 8);
    n = n | (n >> 16);
    n = n | (n >> 32);
    return n + 1;
}
}
```

this is the onCreate code in my activity :

```
    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GLES20Renderer.context = this;

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (hasGLES20()) {
        mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        mGLView.setRenderer(new GLES20Renderer());
    } else {
        mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
        mGLView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        mGLView.setRenderer(new GLES20Renderer());
    Log.i("S"," does not support open gl 2");
        // you gotta get a phone that supports Open GL 2.0
    }

    setContentView(mGLView);
}
```

and this is the code for the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` :

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(boolean firstDraw) {
        int textureid = TextureHelper.loadGLTextureFromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher, context, true, gl);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
}
```

and I think I missed out some code in on draw part maybe :( and I have no  idea how to load the other texture with alpha enabled...

Comment: You have to post also the implementation of GlSurfaceView.Renderer.onSurfaceCreated(...) and onSurfaceChanged(...).

Comment: done, added the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I am wrong, but I suppose that you are beginner in OpenGL. So, I am going to try help you in your learning.

First, I recommend you using OpenGLES 2.0 only, because it is supported by Android 2.2 (API level 8) and higher. Read [Android reference and Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). Today, All android version is greater than API level 8.

For drawing anything with OpenGl ES 2.0, you have to use GLES20.glDrawArrays(..) or GLES20.glDrawElements(..). Read [OpenGl ES 2.0 Reference](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/). I didn't see you are call one of theses methods.

Answer your question: 
There is a lot of ways to control alpha of one image. The easy way is create your own Fragment Shader to do it. Read [this great tutorial](http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/fragment-shader/) to learn the basics step of creating shaders.